# Mysql Round With AVG function with no precision is return wrong value

Tags: mysql

I need to find avg of rating from database with rounded values.I wrote query with avg() is return value correct(4.50000).then i need the rounded value without precision like 5(because avg is 4.50).so i wrote query with round() like as below

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating)) as avgrate FROM `cust_review` WHERE find_in_set(1,'8,1,22')
```

its return the value 4.but the correct answer is 5.I was attached my screenshots below
[image]

before round up the values
[image]

Then my datatype is double(2,1) for rating field

here i edited with table structure
[image]

Comment: *I wrote query with avg() is return value correct(4.50000).* It may be 4.49999999999... which is shown as 4.50000, so it won't be surprize that the rounding will give 4.

Comment: did you need table structure with values??

Comment: @Akina I have also tried like that.its worked.now i added my table data picture friend

Comment: add a snapshot of the data chunk, of which the `avg()` is being taken. i.e. `SELECT rating as avgrate FROM cust_review WHERE find_in_set(1,'8,1,22')`

Comment: What does the statement `Select round(4.50000)` returns on your side?

Comment: it return correctly! 5 bro

Comment: *my datatype is double(2,1) for rating field* For floating-point datatypes this issue is a common one. Try to alter the datatype to DECIMAL. Or add 1/2 of the last digit (0.000005 in your case) before rounding.

Comment: @Akina it's working fine on decimal datatype. Can i post it into the answer section?

Comment: @JeyakumarKumar Of course.

Answer (score 0):

It was worked fine by changing the  datatype from double(2,1) to decimal(2,1).

Comment: This might solve your problem, but it doesn't answer your question, which is about DOUBLE.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in [Rounding Behavior](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-rounding.html):

> The `ROUND()` function rounds differently depending on whether its
>   argument is exact or approximate:
>
> - For exact-value numbers, ROUND() uses the “round half up” rule: A value with a fractional part of .5 or greater is rounded up to the
>     next integer if positive or down to the next integer if negative. (In
>     other words, it is rounded away from zero.) A value with a fractional
>     part less than .5 is rounded down to the next integer if positive or
>     up to the next integer if negative. (In other words, it is rounded
>     toward zero.)
> - For approximate-value numbers, the result depends on the C library. On many systems, this means that `ROUND()` uses the “round to nearest
>     even” rule: A value with a fractional part exactly half way between
>     two integers is rounded to the nearest even integer.

The relevant part is: "**round to nearest even**" - which is 4 for 4.5.

Consider the following example:

```
create table test(
  dcm decimal(2,1),
  dbl double
);

insert into test(dcm,dbl)values
  (4.5,4.5),
  (5.5,5.5);

select dcm, round(dcm), round(dbl) from test;
```

Result:

```
| dcm | round(dcm) | round(dbl) |
| --- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 4.5 | 5          | 4          |
| 5.5 | 6          | 6          |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sP6CQMGVHcpkJaoX1o1fUV/0)

As you can see - the DECIMAL value is always rounded up, while the DOUBLE value is rounded to the nearest even number.

If you want ROUND() to always round up DOUBLE values, you can first cast them to DECIMAL. Example:

```
select dbl, round(cast(dbl as decimal(20,10))) from test;
```

returns

```
| dbl | round(cast(dbl as decimal(20,10))) |
| --- | ---------------------------------- |
| 4.5 | 5                                  |
| 5.5 | 6                                  |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qEwfF5RvJ6zuLtPGLCG4uP/0)

Or you just cast to the corresponding decimal type, which in your case would be something like

```
select cast(dbl as decimal(20,0)) from test;
```

Of course, you can also just store the values in DECICIMAL.